# ionic 3 onesignal handle when notification received

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification, ionic2, ionic3, onesignal

I just started to use OneSignal push notifications system, and I have one problem when I should make some action when user receive notification. I use in my app same code as on Ionic documentation:

```
    this.oneSignal.startInit('my-one-signal-id', 'firebase-id');

    this.oneSignal.inFocusDisplaying(this.oneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.InAppAlert);

    this.oneSignal.handleNotificationReceived().subscribe(() => {
     // do something when notification is received
    });

    this.oneSignal.handleNotificationOpened().subscribe(() => {
      // do something when a notification is opened
    });

    this.oneSignal.endInit();
```

Problem is that handleNotificationReceived function works only when I am in application, when app is killed doesn't work. On other hands handleNotificationOpened function works well even app is killed or run.

What I am trying to do is to save notification in local storage when notification is received. Can someone know how to do that and how to make handleNotificationReceived run even app is killed? Or how to get all unread notifications from OneSignal server (application back-end is out of reach to be changed) when user open application?

I am using Ionic 3, and app should be build in both Android and IOS.

Thanks in advance for answer.